# How to pass a form view to another view as a context in django?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views, django-generic-views

I'm using Django 1.8 to create an application. I have a Link model and a Comment model which has Link as a ForeignKey. I'm using generic views to generate a LinkDetailView and CommentCreateView and show them in separate template files and then include comment in link detail template. Here is the code:

**views.py**

```
class LinkDetailView(DetailView):
    models      = Link
    queryset    = Link.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(LinkDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = CommentForm
        return context

class CommentCreateView(CreateView):
    form_class  = CommentForm
    template_name = "comments/comment_form.html"


    def form_valid(self, form):
        link = get_object_or_404(Link, pk=form.data["link"] )
        f = form.save(commit=False)
        f.user = self.request.user
        f.link = link
        f.save()
        return super(CommentCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

**link_detail.html**

```
{% block content %}
 . . . 
{% include "comments/comment_form.html" %}
{% endblock %}
```

**comment_form.html**

```
<h2>Add Comment</h2>
<form action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        {{ form.as_p }}
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

The form shows up in the link detail page but when I click submit button it goes to nowhere [I see error `"POST /links/1/slug/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0` in shell] and obviously doesn't save in database.

I'm not sure if I've chosen correct approach to do this, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved the problem using FormMixin here's the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/mixins/)

and here's how the views.py looks like now:

```
class LinkDetailView(FormMixin, DetailView):
    models      = Link
    queryset    = Link.objects.all()

    form_class  = CommentForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('link_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk, 'slug': self.object.slug})

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(LinkDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = self.get_form()
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            return HttpResponseForbidden()
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        link = get_object_or_404(Link, pk=self.object.pk)
        print link
        f = form.save(commit=False)
        f.user = self.request.user
        f.link = link
        f.save()
        return super(LinkDetailView, self).form_valid(form)
```